# How to fill array missing elements?

Tags: python

I have a simple arrary:

```
a = [1,2,3,6,7,10,11,12,15,16]
```

How to fill array missing elements ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm just missing something, but what do you mean by "fill array missing elements"?

Answer (score 6):

```
range(min(a), max(a) + 1)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```